# Revert Intellij 14 UI to the default icons

Tags: java, intellij-idea, icons, themes

I imported 2 themes for Intellij Ultimate 14 and now the icons for the Java classses and interfaces changed their look.

http://prntscr.com/766ei6

I would like to revert this change and set the icons back to the original ones from Intellij

http://prntscr.com/766fek

So far I have not found a setting to do this. Switching the theme does not fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like your *Sources Root* is wrong and has nothing to do with the themes itself. You have to mark your source-directory as *sources root*.

To do this, right click on the sources root (e.g. your `src` folder), choose *Mark directory As* > *Sources Root*. If the *Sources Root* option is not available in the sub-menu, please ensure that no other folder is marked as *Sources Root*. The Sources Root is highlighted by a blue folder-icon.

For further reading, please click [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html).

Regards

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution to my problem :)